# Reading Data from Firebase Database using React-Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

We are trying to use react-native to read data from a Firebase Realtime Database. For some reason we are able to write data to the database using `.ref().set()`, but if we try to use `.ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) { 
}`, the promise will not be validated. Any advice on the proper syntax for making this call and using the value from the snapshot to update the state of the class.

Comment: Show the code you currently have.

Comment: Are you using any kind of library? I recommend using firestack as its pretty stable and it wraps nicely around the firebase sdk